# Как указать DRIVER PATH и BROWSER PATH в Selenium-webdriver

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, hosting

Недавно я написал небольшой проект по парсингу данных с сайта. При попытке запустить его удаленно на шаред хостинге **Cpanel** у меня возникли проблемы:
`

```
There was an error managing chrome (error sending request for url (https://googlechromelabs.github.io/chrome-for-testing/last-known-good-versions-with-downloads.json): operation timed out); using driver found in the cache
/home/yanvolyn/nodevenv/testbot.yanvolynets.tech/18/lib/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/error.js:524
    let err = new ctor(data.message)
              ^

WebDriverError: unknown error: cannot find Chrome binary`
```

И также у меня ложиться весь хостинг. Я думаю, что надо скачать Chrome и его засунуть в какую-нибудь директорию и указать туда путь. Вот код:
`

```
const { Builder, By, until } = require('selenium-webdriver');
const chrome = require('selenium-webdriver/chrome')
(async () => {
  let driver = await new Builder()
    .forBrowser('chrome')
    .setChromeOptions(new chrome.Options().headless())
    .build();
})();
```

`